# Why do I get the error message "unspecified format specification"?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I tried scraping the first two pages of topics from this discussion forum by using this code but received an error message which I do not understand - `"Error in sprintf(url_base, i) : unrecognised format specification '%2C'"`

Can someone help? Thanks.

```
library(rvest)

library(purrr)

url_base <- "http://www.epilepsy.com/connect/forums/living-epilepsy-adults?page=0%2C"

map_df(1:2, function(i) {

  # simple but effective progress indicator
  cat(".")

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))

  data.frame(title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".field-content a")),
             excerpt=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".field-content p")),
             date=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".views-field-created .field-content")),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}) -> epilepsyforum

df <- data.frame(epilepsyforum)


write.csv(df,"epilepsyforum.csv")
```

Comment: you probably want `paste0()` rather than `sprintf()`

Comment: If you want to go the `sprintf` way, you would need to modify the `url_base` to `http://www.epilepsy.com/connect/forums/living-epilepsy-adults?page=0%2C%s` (added %s at the end) and then use `sprintf(url_base, i)`.

Comment: Thank you Roman Luštrik, SymbolixAU and shwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with:

```
pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
```

but this works just fine for the url you specified:

```
pg <- read_html(url_base)
```

Like mentioned in the comment above, if you're trying to loop through pages, then use:

```
pg <- read_html(paste0(url_base,i))
```